# Cypress: Handle dynamic dropdown to avoid "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectize' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, cypress

I would like to know how to select an option from a dynamic dropdown using cypress. I tried several configs, but I always get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectize' of undefined"

The element is defined as follows:

```html
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" style="display: block; left: 7.5px; width: 465px; top: 156.75px; bottom: auto;" id="select2-drop" xpath="1">   <div class="select2-search">       
<label for="s2id_autogen21_search" class="select2-offscreen">Case</label>       
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-21" id="s2id_autogen21_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-25">
</div>
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-21"><li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-25" role="option">
<span class="project">XXXLutz vs Mobelix</span><br><span class="client">Wisozk - Turner</span></div></li></ul></div>
```

I tried with the next code:

```js
cy.get(this.elements.caseNameSelector).trigger('mousemove').click()
            .get('.select2-search input').eq(4)
            .type(caseName, {force:true})
            .wait(2000)
            .get('.select2-result-label 
    .project').trigger('mousemove').click({force:true})`
```

Also tried this:

```js
cy
    .get(this.elements.caseNameSelector).trigger('mousemove').click()
    .get('.select2-search input').eq(4).type(caseName).type('{enter}', 
     { release: false }).get('.select2-result-label .project').click()
```